# Find a common expression (parameterized by y = 1/2, 1 and 2) uniting three (rational) polynomials in k

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, random-matrices, discrete-mathematics, quaternions

I am seeking a common "simple" expression (preferably/presumably a sum of products of linear factors, or sum of products of low-degree factors) uniting the  three polynomials (parameterized by $y=\frac{1}{2}$, $1$ and $2$) below. The common expression will be of fourth-degree in  $k$ and of arbitrary degree (probably between $3$ and $6$) in $y$.

For $y=\frac{1}{2}$ (the real case), the polynomial is

$-(y=\frac{15}{4})$ $(294 + 413 k + 213 k^2 + 48 k^3 + 4 k^4) = -(15/4) (2 + k) (3 + k) (7 + 2 k)^2.$

For $y = 1$ (the complex case), the polynomial is

$-24 (990 + 873 k + 280 k^2 + 39 k^3 + 2 k^4) = -24 (3 + k) (5 + k) (6 + k) (11 + 2 k).$

For $y = 2$ (the quaternionic case), the polynomial (NOT now the product of linear factors) is

$-60 (13134 + 6925 k + 1291 k^2 + 103 k^3 + 3 k^4) = -60 (11 + k) (1194 + k (521 + k (70 + 3 k))).$

A common expression for $y=\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$ is

$-4 y (1 + y) (2 + y) (1 + k + 2 y) (1 + k + 4 y) (1 + k + 5 y) (3 + 2 k + 8 y),$

but not for $y = 2.$

This question has pertinence to random matrix theory and quantum information topics
(cf.[Arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.2560)).